# How to let views's sort criteria random equally

Tags: 7, views

I have two node content. I want to know which content is able to convince user to sign up.

I create a views block and two node contents. The views will randomly choose one node content and display.

At the views sort criteria, I choose global random, but it does not random equally. It choose option A more than option B.

Question: How to let it choose random equally or alternate such as A,B,A,B,A,B..etc?

Comment: you are doing it right. Now it depends on that function to pick up random item each time. I think if you add more contents, it will perform better.

Comment: @PankajSachdeva, Thanks for your reply. Problem is I prefer alternate. I want to compare which content is able to convince user to sign up. I only have two contents. As a result, I cant compare if it dun random equally.

Comment: You mean there are content type A and B and each one has a few nodes. and you need alternatively show a random content from A then B then A and ... . right?

Comment: `A,B,A,B,A,B` is not considered random, they are alternating. There is no such thing as "Random Equally".

Comment: `it choose option A more than option B` just like tossing a coin, you may get H, H, H, T, H, H, T, H, H, H but if you do it 1000 times it usually balances out to almost 50/50

Comment: Is caching involved at all? If so that block/view should not be cached. There are modules that allow you to pull in dynamic content even in a cache environment, such as Authcache. And if you want to alternate you should let views pull in both and override views template and hide one and persist your alternating variable somehow. Or perhaps do your own block and pick your node there.

Comment: @Drupalist, two nodes at one content type.

Comment: @J.Reynolds, my caching is not involved at all. :)

Comment: @NoSssweat, Thank for your reply. I hope it wont get worst. (Hoping to look for better solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable core **Statistics** module, you get some more filters in views:

- Content statistics: Most recent view
- Content statistics: Total views
- Content statistics: Views today

You can select one of them, and sort ascending. So that it will always show the least recent viewed node, or least viewed node in all times, or least viewed node today, respectively which filter you've chosen.